# MySQL Order by DESC if column = X, otherwise ASC

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How do I order query by start_date DESC if `finished` = 1, otherwise start_date ASC. Right now it looks as this:

```
SELECT game_id, 
    event_id, 
    start_date, 
    best_of, 
    home_team_id, 
    away_team_id, 
    home_value, 
    away_value, 
    home_result, 
    away_result, 
    stream_url, 
    stats_url, 
    comments, 
    finished 
FROM betting_games 
ORDER BY finished ASC, 
    start_date ASC 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT *
FROM betting_games
ORDER BY finished ASC, 
         CASE 
            WHEN finished =  1 THEN - 1 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date)
            ELSE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date)
         END ASC
```

You cannot return `DESC` or `ASC` from a `CASE` expression. Using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, date field `start_date` is converted into an integer, that can be used to store in descending order (once negated).

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b977f/3)